# react-redux error messaging best practices

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, error-messaging

new to react, just starting to work on a react-redux application.
Just wondering does anyone have any tips on best practices relating to form validation and displaying error messages? 
Any thoughts on this greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Looking at redux-form as a possible solution (might be a bit much to start out with though) or else maybe something like material-ui with a custom validator to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The react way is to have a container handle the state and pass it through the props to the inputs (components). So it's not really a react-redux thing to handle a validation, if of course you don't build through multiple routes and need that global state.

Answer (score 0):

I like using [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) for forms in React. The main benefits are:

- **Validation and error messages**
- Handling forms state
- Handling form submission

And it is a good idea to use [Yup](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) (a schema validator) with Formik.

Here is an example of a form with Formik + Yup:

`yarn add formik yup`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  : Yup.string()
    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
    .max(50, 'Too Long!')
    .required('Required'),
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Invalid email')
    .required('Required'),
});

export const ValidationSchemaExample = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Signup</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: '',
        email: '',
      }}
      validationSchema={SignupSchema}
      onSubmit={values => {
        // same shape as initial values
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      {({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field name="name" />
          {errors.name && touched.name ? (
            <div>{errors.name}</div>
          ) : null}
          <Field name="email" type="email" />
          {errors.email && touched.email ? <div>{errors.email}</div> : null}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);
```